# What did the Apollo missions do with old LiOH canisters & the water they produced?

Tags: apollo-program, life-support

We all love the [Apollo 13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_13) story, but the famous [lithium hydroxide CO<sub>2</sub> scrubber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_dioxide_scrubber#Lithium_hydroxide) of that mission has made it hard for me to find information about its regular use.

What happened to the old canisters after they were used up? Were they manually replaced? Were they soggy & wet & have to be wrapped up or otherwise prevented from leaking? Were they tossed behind the seats with the poop bags?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The canisters were manually replaced. Here is the appropriate checklist section.

[image]

From [CSM Operations Checklist](https://history.nasa.gov/afj/ap11fj/a11-csmocindex.html) Section 10 Systems Management

Used canisters were stowed in the container that the unused canister was removed from.

> The CO2-odor absorber filter change sequence involves numerically
>   identified filters and alphabetically identified filter stowage
>   containers. Although the filters are replaced in numerical sequence,
>   the stowage containers are not opened in alphabetical sequence
>   relative to filter replacement.    Odd-numbered filters will always
>   be installed in suit circuit canister A (upper) and even-numbered
>   filters installed in canister B (lower). After the proper filter
>   stowage container is located by the crewman, the correct filter is
>   obtained and the filter change accomplished. **The used filter is then stowed in
>   the container from which the unused replacement came**. Where two
>   filters are stowed one above the other, the used filter will always be
>   placed below the remaining unused filter. This provides a more readily
>   accessible unused filter at the next 12-hour replacement period. Filter replacement
>   data, such as filter number and mission time, is recorded by the crew in the flight log.

From [*Apollo Operations Handbook*](https://www.ibiblio.org/apollo/Documents/SM2A-03-SC012-ApolloOperationsHandbook-Spacecraft012.pdf) page 2.7-10 (emphasis mine)

Answer (score 22):

> 1. What happened to the old canisters after they were used up? Were they manually replaced? Were they tossed behind the seats?

@OrganicMarble's [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/41073/33950) covers this with reliable sources quoted.

I only wish to add (after going through Apollo-7 to Apollo-11 flight journals), the exact mentioned in communication compartment numbers with (square type Command Module) LiOH canisters:

- Apollo-7: A-2 (fresh canisters)
- Apollo-8: A-3 (fresh canisters)
- Apollo-9: A-5 (fresh canisters); B-5 (used canisters)
- Apollo-10: A-3 (used canisters)
- Apollo-11: B-6 (used canisters, to be later discarded with LM jettison  to free up the space for moon soil samples)

Below is the graphical description of the compartments  borrowed from [Apollo-13 Flight Journal](https://history.nasa.gov/afj/ap13fj/05day2-mcc2-tv.html):
[image]

The two types of cylindrical LiOH canisters in LM module, as well as cylindrical LiOH canister in PLSS were meant to be discarded either by jettisoning onto the lunar surface or with the ascent stage (being installed in the Environment Control System).

> 2. Were they soggy & wet & have to be wrapped up or otherwise prevented from leaking?

This [NASA document](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.nasa.gov/pdf/519341main_AP_ED_CO2Removal_Therm.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwivlO_fgqPnAhWPTX0KHXwRBnoQFjAAegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw2Z4iptc-ONbGtX1A4OdlXp) (although related to Shuttle CO<sub>2</sub> scrubbing systems) and this [CO<sub>2</sub> scrubber Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_dioxide_scrubber) (describing a generic LiOH CO<sub>2</sub> scrubber) suggest that chemical reaction between solid LiOH and gaseous CO<sub>2</sub> produces **gaseous** H<sub>2</sub>O as by-product:

> 2LiOH(s) + CO<sub>2</sub>(g) → Li<sub>2</sub>CO<sub>3</sub>(s) + H<sub>2</sub>O(g)

The reaction is exothermic, so perhaps the generated water vapour wasn't readily condensing within the LiOH bed itself. There were other systems to remove moisture from the circulated air, so the moisture from the CO<sub>2</sub> scrubbing process would just add an additional load on those systems.

I believe that the assumption of the canisters being dry can be supported by the following [quote from Apollo-7](https://history.nasa.gov/afj/ap07fj/a7_07_day4.html) crew when they were trying to troubleshoot the case of water leaking from the oxygen hose:

> 079:29:19 Cunningham: Roger. We also just discovered water coming out of our blue hoses, at least the one in the center couch...
>
> 080:15:40 Cunningham: Roger. And we checked our **lithium hydroxide canisters**. They **are dry**.

Having said that, there was an issue with CO<sub>2</sub> removal in LM after lift-off from the Moon, during rendezvous with CSM [Apollo-11 Flight Journal Day6/Part2](https://history.nasa.gov/afj/ap11fj/19day6-rendezvs-dock.html), when Mission Control suggested it **might have been** due to some water channeling inside the canister:

> 126:01:15 Evans: Eagle, Houston. Could you verify you switched lithium hydroxide canisters? Over.
>
> 126:01:24 Aldrin: That's affirmative. We started getting an erratic indication on primary [LiOH canister], so we switched to secondary [LiOH canister], and it was again erratic, and I thought it might have been a sensor. But it's settled down now, and we're on the secondary. Over.
>
> 126:48:47 Evans: Roger. In the event of the possibility that we **may have had some water channeling in those hydroxide canisters**, we recommend you stay in the cabin mode from now on. Over.

The above quote may be interpreted in the way that potential water in the canisters were treated as a source of malfunction rather than being a normal operation.

Emphasis added

Comment: Fantastic answer! If I could give two accepted, I would. Thank you for answering my second question in such thorough detail.

Comment: Think you're right about the water. On shuttle the condensing heat exchanger which removed water vapor from the air loop was placed just after the LiOH canisters. https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/pdf/383445main_eclss_21002.pdf page 3-2

Comment: @OrganicMarble The CO2 absorbition with LiOH works better with humid air than with dry air, therefore the condensing heat exchanger should not be placed before the LiOH canisters within the air loop.